# jquery remove the .change() handler

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have been trying to figure out how to remove the `.change()` jquery handler but have had no luck. I am using it to activate some form fields when a radio button is selected, but I don't want it to fire for every subsequent change.

```
$('.radio').change(function(){
    alert("changed");
    $('.fields').removeAttr('disabled');
    //this is where I try removing the change handler
    $(this).off('change');
});
```

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5jqqgnt/3/)

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine what you want exactly. When do you need the change handler and when don't you need it?

Comment: I need it on page load. I basically only want it to fire once (since radio buttons cannot be under by the user)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code was only removing the handler from the radio button that was changed and not from the group

change

```
// 'this' only removing the handler from the radio button that was changed
$(this).off('change');
```

to

```
// removing the handler of all radio button
$('.radio').off('change');
```

your code

```
$('.radio').change(function(){
  alert("changed");
  $('.fields').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('.radio').off('change');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q5jqqgnt/3/

Comment: my original code was only removing the handler from the radio button that was changed and not from the group. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code actually works, but only problem is that you are turning off the "Change" event only for the Radio button that you are clicking. Try to use `$(".radio").off('change');` instead of `$(this).off('change');`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @JLRishe. I mistook name for id, in his JSFiddle!